# Android Garbage Collector takes too much time

Tags: android, kotlin, garbage-collection

I am working on an Android App in the area of Computer Graphics right now. As you probably know, CG is all about pixels and vectors (in 3D).

My problem currently is that I have to calculate multiple vectors for each pixel (usually around Full-HD: 1920 x 1080) multiple times a second. That leaves me with ... alot of `Vec3D`-Objects (32-Byte each). It is not that much memory ( < 100 MB) but somehow the Android Garbage Collector can't live without cleaning up which takes around 100ms (crazy long).

Initially I thought all those objects would be optimized by the `Kotlin`-Compiler so I didn't worry about it while developing - but it seems like that's not the case!

As you can imagine, most of the time the GC is running instead of my App. I already thought about a `Vec3D-Factory` which only creates a `Vec3D`-Object once but because `Vec3D` is using three `double` variables I don't think this would change too much.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unclear if you read: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips What you describe is somewhat similar to gaming so https://developer.android.com/games/optimize may be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely read those.

Answer (score 1):

[Pools are typically used for minimizing object instantiation and collection.](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html) You can create a base pool class like this:

```
abstract class Pool<T> {
    private val objects = Stack<T>()

    protected abstract fun instantiate(): T
    protected abstract fun reset(obj: T)

    fun obtain(): T {
        return try {
            objects.pop()
        } catch (e: EmptyStackException){
            instantiate()
        }
    }

    fun free(obj: T){
        reset(obj)
        objects.push(obj)
    }

}
```

Then create an implementation for the type of object you're creating:

```
class Vec3DPool : Pool<Vec3D>() {
    override fun instantiate(): Vec3D = Vec3D()

    override fun reset(obj: Vec3D) {
        obj.apply {
            x = 0.0
            y = 0.0
            z = 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need a new object, call `pool.obtain()` instead of instantiating a new one. Whenever you're done with an object, return it to the pool with `pool.free()` before its reference is lost. The pool will hang onto it so the GC won't be triggered.

Comment: Ohh, so basically what this does is creating as minimal of objects as possible and instead changes the properties of already created ones? That's genius!

Comment: Yep. Care does need to be taken that you don't accidentally continue using an object after freeing it, or you'll have subtle bugs. The `reset` function is optional. For something like a vector, you can omit it and just don't assume you're getting a zero-length vector from the pool.

Comment: I just implemented it and nothings works. And it is just ugly to look at. Man I hate Android